# warning: unknown enum constant Mode.LOCAL

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

```
warning: unknown enum constant Mode.LOCAL   
reason: class file for com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe$Mode not found 
1 warning 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: /Users/s/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.2.5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 
Note: /Users/s/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/android/src/main/java/com/example/flutternativeimage/FlutterNativeImagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 
Note: /Users/s/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/location-4.4.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location/FlutterLocation.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I've a flutter project and above are the warning logs I'm getting every time when I click run or type `flutter run` command.

Please help me to effectively resolve the cause of a warning. Despite my efforts, I have been unable to determine the specific source of the warning.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @aled How can I effectively resolve the cause of a warning message in my code or application? Despite my efforts, I have been unable to determine the specific source of the warning.

Comment: The warning is very generic. It gives you instructions to get the specific details. No one can tell what is the issue without details. Have you followed the instructions? Once you do if you can't resolve the issue, then post a question.